# Second Monitor Displaying at Half Horizontal Resolution

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, amdgpu, dvi

My second monitor is 1980x1080. It's set to 1980x1080 in display settings. Xrandr says it's at 1920x1080. But my monitor reports receiving a 960x1080 signal (and the image looks as if that is the case.)
The monitor is connected to my RX580 through a DVI-to-HDMI adapter cable.

Here's the relevant xrandr output:

```
    DVI-D-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (0x5b) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 480mm x 270mm
    Identifier: 0x59
    Timestamp:  698786
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       1
    CRTCs:      1 0 2 3 4 5
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    _MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff001e6d555b01010101
        011a010380301b78ea3135a5554ea126
        0c5054a54b00714f81809500b300a9c0
        810081c090402a4480a0703827403020
        3500e00e1100001e000000fd00304b1e
        5512000a202020202020000000fc004c
        472046554c4c2048440a2020023a8018
        71382d40582c4500e00e1100001e01b3
        020324f148900403011012131f230907
        078301000065030c001000681a000001
        01304b00023a801871382d40582c4500
        e00e1100001e00000000000000000000
        0000000000000000011d007251d01e20
        6e285500e00e1100001e8c0ad08a20e0
        2d10103e9600e00e1100001800000000
        00000000000000000000000000000082
    GAMMA_LUT_SIZE: 4096 
        range: (0, -1)
    DEGAMMA_LUT_SIZE: 4096 
        range: (0, -1)
    GAMMA_LUT: 0 
        range: (0, 65535)
    CTM: 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
        0 1 
    DEGAMMA_LUT: 0 
        range: (0, 65535)
    TearFree: auto 
        supported: off, on, auto
    underscan vborder: 54 
        range: (0, 128)
    underscan hborder: 96 
        range: (0, 128)
    underscan: off 
        supported: off, on, auto
    scaling mode: None 
        supported: None, Full, Center, Full aspect
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CONNECTOR_ID: 64 
        supported: 64
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
  1920x1080 (0x5b) 174.500MHz +HSync +VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  83.89KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1119           clock  74.97Hz
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Adding amdgpu.dc back to my grub command line fixed the issue, but my splash screen got garbled. I ended up disabling the splash screen.